# Android: Background color in TableLayout

Tags: android

I'd like to set background color in my tablelayout view and I can't, because it doesnt paint the entire screen. My goal is to have 2 circle buttons in the center (horizontally and vertically) of the screen and background blue. 
What I have right now is this:

[image]

the background color doesn't fill all screen.

and I have the following code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#8ad5f0"
    tools:context="com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.SignActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Extensive"

        android:background="@drawable/default_button_selector"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:id="@+id/extensive"
        android:textColor="#079dd0"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
```

If I change the following 2 lines to match_parent:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

I get this:

[image]

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your tablelayout into a FrameLayout, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="#8ad5f0"

<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="#8ad5f0"
             tools:context="com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.SignActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Extensive"

    android:background="@drawable/default_button_selector"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
    android:id="@+id/extensive"
    android:textColor="#079dd0"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>
</TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you will use android:layout_weight="1". in button property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick, but is not proper code :-)

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#8ad5f0"
tools:context="com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope.SignActivity">
<View android:layout_weight="1">

</View>

<Button
    android:text="Extensive"
    android:background="#F90"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
    android:id="@+id/extensive"
    android:textColor="#079dd0"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>

<Button
    android:text="blabla"

    android:background="#F90"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
    android:id="@+id/blabla"
    android:textColor="#079dd0"
    android:textSize="12dp"
  />

<View android:layout_weight="1">

</View>
```